# How do you Unit TEst code which uses String.IsNullOrEmpty?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Do you write two Unit Tests? One for value being Null and one for value being string.Empty? The similar  for string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()?

Comment: This is not about testing internal .NET methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I'd use `NUnit` test cases to test these permutations.
They'll give you coverage of the three different checks without duplicating your test code.

For example:

```
[TestCase("")]
[TestCase(null)]
public class SomeTest(string stringValue)
{
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(()=> CheckIfNullOrEmpty(stringValue));
}

public void CheckIfNullOrEmpty(string val)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
   {
       throw new ArgumentException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would typically want to test that all possible classes of inputs (null, empty, whitespace, non-whitespace) get the right outputs.

That means testing both alternatives for `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` and all three alternatives for `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()`.

Comment: I thought so, but some test are quite "long liners" and in this case it is just a Copy and Paste(which is against DRY principle).

Comment: It's not exactly a copy-paste, as it tests different scenarios. DRY is a principle, not a hard rule. Add as many tests as you need in order to feel confident about your code base.

Comment: All possible inputs? Even testing only all possible strings containing only spaces: " ", "  ", "   ", ... is a) not really practical, because their number is bounded by your memory size (and what if there is more memory on your production than on your testing server, oh my, we have uncovered possibilities!) b) is waste of your time! People don't be so religious (==irrational admiration) about unit testing :(

Comment: @Steves I said *"inputs"*, but what I meant was *"classes of input"*. I edited my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you shouldn't be testing functionality provided by the framework. Treat methods such as this as tools in a tool kit that have been tested by Microsoft.

Instead you should focus on testing the output of your code which uses this method. There must be different logical paths of operation which are dependent on whether the string in question is null or empty and these are what you should focus on with your tests.

Comment: Yes, there is a workflow which is based on String.IsNullOrWhitespace() result. Lets say a method should execute MethodA if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(p)) and MethodB if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(p)). Would you create four tests? p = null, p = string.Empty, p = "\n \r", p = "value"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not rule on how many unit test you have to write, but I see 4+ cases you need to check:

Code under test:

```
public string MyMethod(string s){
//Do stuff
  if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)){
    return "failed";
  } else {
    return "passed";
  }
}
```

Because you are testing a black box the following cases:

```
NULL
""
"   "
"A"
```

And you probably need to do some more like:

```
" A "
"AAAA"
etc
```

When unit testing the main focus should be on the 'good' case. So I would expect more tests for pass then fail.